# How to get a path a class is loaded from

Tags: java, classpath

I want to list *some* classes on the classpath, but I don't want all of them (moreover, scanning the whole classpath is pretty slow). Given a single `ExampleClass`, I want to get all classes residing in the same classpath entry (i.e., directory or JAR, other cases can be ignored). There's a single ClassLoader.

Using `ExampleClass.class.getResource("/")` does not work as I always get the first classpath entry, e.g.,

```
/whatever/build/classes/main/
```

`ExampleClass.class.getResource(".")` returns a child of the proper entry, e.g.,

```
/whatever/build/classes/test/somepackage/ExampleClass.class
```

which is something I could process to

```
/whatever/build/classes/test/
```

But I wonder if there's a better way than fooling around with strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
URL url = ExampleClass.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
```

Check for null however.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
    package foo;
    public class Test
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            ClassLoader loader = Test.class.getClassLoader();
            System.out.println(loader.getResource("foo/Test.class"));
        }
   }
```

Output is:

```
file:/C:/Users/Jon/Test/foo/Test.class
```